# Multi-account Google Calendar free/busy status?

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, scheduling

I have three G Suite accounts and a personal Google account, and until recently, there was little need for the Google Calendar to have any real use.

Now however the powers that be finally discovered the smart re-scheduler and the other Google tools for managing meetings and schedules; unfortunately I'm now in a position where I've got events notifications all over the place and because each of the calendars do not know about each other, I'm losing all of the advantages of rescheduler / free-busy status.

TL;DR, Four calendars, unified 'free/busy' status without having to manually copy every event please.

Comment: This is one feature that Google Calendar is seriously lacking.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not currently available in Google Calender.

And it is very unlikely to have any Grease-monkey Script/ Google Chrome Extension/ Java Script to perform such a function.

Also, Google Labs is now down, otherwise there would have been a little hope.